# initial setup,apache restart failing

Tags: wordpress

doing the initial setup for apache, and myphp, I get this message when I try to restart my apache:
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.72. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Answer (score 0):

This should be a warning not a problem with Apache server.
If you insert below line in either httpd.conf or apache2.conf in `/etc/apache2` and restart apache the notice will disappear.

```
ServerName localhost
```

It will not work for virtual host. Make sure you have defined server name inside `/etc/hosts` with specific ip address